# ASP.NET FormsAuthentication won't redirect to Default.aspx in root

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I've got forms authentication setup as follows:

Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="180" loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" name=".ASPXVEWPAUTH"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Login.aspx:

```
/**Auth logic in button click**/
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false);
```

The Login.aspx and Default.aspx pages both live in the root of the application.

Every time I login it redirects me back to the login page. If I just go straight to Default.aspx, it redirects me to the login page as it should, puts Default.aspx into the returnUrl query string as it should, then when I login it redirects me back to Login.aspx with no query string. If I try to login again, with no query string, it still just goes back to Login.aspx.

If I change defaultUrl to a page outside of the root, it redirects fine, no problem.

If I change `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false);` to just `Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");`, the redirect still doesn't work.

If I change `<deny users="?" />` to `<allow users="?" />`, I can load Default.aspx just fine by going directly to it, but the redirect still doesn't work.

I'm at a complete loss here. I've never seen this behaviour before and I'm out of ideas to try. Why won't it let me redirect to a page inside the root of the application? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an IIS Express problem.
I tried running it on my local IIS and it worked fine. I reinstalled IIS express and it also seems to work fine now.